# streaming and transforming a Firestore document snapshots() stream

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, repository

I am trying to get a document stream from Firestore, to extract one of its fields in my repository and to stream the field to my bloc. I use `return orderBriefDoc.snapshots().map((snapshot) {` for this.

However, upon first call, no internal map instruction becomes executed and instead I receive a type mismatch `type '_MapStream<DocumentSnapshot, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<List<OrderBrief>>'`. I do not understand why the return type of the `.map()` method does not depend on what I return within its return statement and why this internal code is not executed.

First of all, I used the repository function of Felix Angelov's Firebase authentication ant of the todo list as a blueprint:

```dart
Stream<User> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map((firebaseUser) {
      return firebaseUser == null ? User.empty : firebaseUser.toUser;
    });
}

Stream<List<Todo>> todos() {
  return todoCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents
        .map((doc) => Todo.fromEntity(TodoEntity.fromSnapshot(doc)))
        .toList();
  });
}
```

My adaption looks like this

```dart
@override
Stream<List<OrderBrief>> orderBriefs() {
  if (orderBriefDoc == null)
    getOrderCollection();
  return orderBriefDoc.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
    final tmp = snapshot;
    print ("2");
    final tmp2 = snapshot.data()['orderBriefs'];
    print("3");
    return snapshot.data()['orderBriefs'].map((orderBrief) {
      final tmp=orderBrief;
      final tmp2 = OrderBriefEntity.fromMap(orderBrief);
      final tmp3 = OrderBrief.fromEntity(tmp2);
      return tmp3;
    }).toList();
  });
}
```

For some reason "2" and "3" are not printed upon first call, and due to the type mismatch the app execution fails. So in my function `orderBriefs()` I return a `.map()` of a `snapshots()` stream. The mapped value, so the single document `snapshot` is mapped again to extract the `orderBriefs` field. This field is transformed from an storage entity class `OrderBriefEntity` to my business logic class `OrderBrief`. The transformation result is the final return value. Hence I would expect the function `orderBriefs()` to return a list stream of this transformation result. However, a `_MapStream<DocumentSnapshot, dynamic>` is returned. Why?

PS: This refers to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431573/streaming-fields-of-a-firestore-document-from-repository-to-bloc), but with a slightly different angle

Answer (score 2):

So, finally I found a method to stream a single document of Firestore. I finally had the idea to look up the documentation of Stream and found a working example there. Why it does not work with only the map method like Felix did it, no idea. That being said, I still follow his pattern to transform the snapshot to an "entity" and then further to the data structure used by the bloc and the ui.

I finally needed to flavors, stream a single field (nested array) of a document and stream a whole document

(1) Streaming a field of a document.

```dart
  @override
  Stream<List<OrderBrief>> orderBriefs() async* {
    if (orderBriefDoc == null)
      getOrderCollection();
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> source = orderBriefDoc.snapshots();
    await for (var snapshot in source) {
      final List<OrderBrief> returnVal = snapshot.data()['orderBriefs'].map<OrderBrief>((orderBrief) {
        return OrderBrief.fromEntity(OrderBriefEntity.fromMap(orderBrief));
      }).toList();
      yield returnVal;
    }
  }
```

(2) Streaming a document with all of its fields

```dart
  @override
  Stream<Order> orderStream(String orderId) async* {
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> source = orderBriefDoc.collection('orders').doc(orderId).snapshots();
    await for (var snapshot in source) {
      final Order returnVal = Order.fromEntity(OrderEntity.fromSnapshot(snapshot));
      yield returnVal;
    }
  }
```

How to neatly integrate this with a listener in the bloc, you will find in the [Firestore ToDos example](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirestoretodostutorial) at bloclibrary